# Why is SQLAlchemy execute Update not working

Tags: python, mysql, transactions, sqlalchemy, pyramid

I have the following:

```
@periodic_task(run_every=crontab(minute="*/1"))
def PeriodicUpdateAgentLastRica():
    query = """update agents
            inner join
               (select sims.consignment_agents_id as agents_id,
                MAX(sims.rica_current_stamp) 
            as last_rica_stamp
            from sims
            where sims.rica_current_stamp > DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 3 MONTH) and sims.consignment_agents_id is not NULL
            group by sims.consignment_agents_id) as dt on dt.agents_id = agents.id
            set agents.last_rica_stamp = dt.last_rica_stamp"""
    res = Session.execute(query)
    print res
    if res.rowcount:
        log.info("Updated %s agents" % res.rowcount)
    #transaction.commit()
```

When I run `celery worker -B` This is what is returned:

```
[2014-02-12 09:15:00,012: INFO/MainProcess] Received task: prepaid.models.Prepaid.PeriodicUpdateAgentLastRica[9ca091c8-595f-4163-8ddf-2742e573b90c]
[2014-02-12 09:15:01,812: WARNING/Worker-7] <sqlalchemy.engine.result.ResultProxy object at 0x776f310>
[2014-02-12 09:15:01,813: INFO/Worker-7] Updated 2923 agents 
[2014-02-12 09:15:01,816: INFO/MainProcess] Task prepaid.models.Prepaid.PeriodicUpdateAgentLastRica[9ca091c8-595f-4163-8ddf-2742e573b90c] succeeded in 1.798980095s: None
```

Even though it says that it updated: `Updated 2923 agents`, when I check the DB, no record is changed.

There is nothing wrong with the query, as when I run it in mySQL Workbench it works.

The same happens when I try forcing [AutoCommit](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_8/core/connections.html#understanding-autocommit), i.e.

```
res = Session.execute(text(query).execution_options(autocommit=True))
```

So it committing, but still the `Update` is not affecting the DB. 
Why is it not affecting the database? Why is it not working?

**UPDATE**

I have also tried doing:

```
with transaction.manager:
    #Rest of code
```

But it still does not change anything in the DB

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This looks like you are using zodb transaction manager in pyramid.

You have to mark the session as changed

http://www.upfrontsystems.co.za/Members/izak/sysadman/how-to-commit-a-transaction-even-when-sqlalchemy-thinks-the-session-is-clean

You should do something like

```
from zope.sqlalchemy import mark_changed
mark_changed(Session)
```

if that does not work try

```
from zope.sqlalchemy import ZopeTransactionExtension
Session.configure(extension=ZopeTransactionExtension('changed'))
```

Comment: It gives me the follwing error: `Task prepaid.models.Prepaid.PeriodicUpdateAgentLastRica[260cb057-c117-4c68-bb08-a55a169ce684] raised unexpected: AttributeError("'scoped_session' object has no attribute 'twophase'",)`

Comment: An alternative is to mark it changed before you perform the operation. see above.

Comment: In my case it worked by passing `mark_changed(Session())`