# Pyramid dbsession always does rollback

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, pyramid

I'm trying to use pyramid's transaction manager to commit the changes. Unfortunately every time, they're rolled back regardless of what I do.

I tried the simple:

```
def handle(conn):
    conn.execute('''ALTER TABLE ....''')

with bootstrap(sys.argv[1]) as env:
    with env['request'].tm:
        handle(env['request'].dbsession)
```

As well as dropping down to connection and creating explicit transaction:

```
def handle(conn):
    with conn.begin() as tran:
        conn.execute('''ALTER TABLE ....''')
        tran.commit()

with bootstrap(sys.argv[1]) as env:
    with env['request'].tm:
        handle(env['request'].dbsession.connection())
```

and a few other ways, but every time, I'm getting a `ROLLBACK` instead of a `COMMIT`.

Doing a simple commit at the end of the first case results in:

```
Error: Transaction must be committed using the transaction manager
```

I'm quite lost at what what is sqlalchemy actually doing in this case - why do I get a "success" with a rollback? What should I do to commit? What would it look like in case of a nested, explicit transaction inside `handle`?

Comment: Until someone else gives an answer, suggest looking at the example in the [SQLAlchemy + URL dispatch wiki tutorial](https://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/tutorials/wiki2/).

Comment: It's not so much what SQLA is doing, but what the combination of SQLA and the Zope transaction manager is doing. A probable cause is that your text statements are not recognized as data changing operations and so the transaction manager thinks it is ok to just rollback. Mark you session explicitly as changed and report back: http://blog.bodu.io/2016/04/24/Zope-Transaction-Manager-Not-Committing-Your-Changes-Try-Marking-the-Session-as-Dirty/.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21058721/insert-not-working-for-sqlalchemy-database-session, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21721545/why-is-sqlalchemy-execute-update-not-working

Answer (score 2):

As ilja said in the comments, the right answer is that when you're operating on the connection directly and not on the ORM session via ORM operations, it's not possible for zope.sqlalchemy to know whether you changed things or not. By default, zope.sqlalchemy requires you to either use the ORM or to mark the session changed manually.

```
from zope.sqlalchemy import mark_changed

mark_changed(env['request'].dbsession)
```

Alternatively, if this is a common pattern for you then you can configure zope.sqlalchemy to just always assume the session was changed and thus issue commits instead of rollbacks by default.

```
zope.sqlalchemy.register(..., initial_state='changed')
```

You already have a call like this somewhere in your code and you just need to add the `initial_state` attribute.